# Create an array of objects, Error of no matching constructor initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

I am trying to create an array of object BuyOrder

```
BuyOrder buy[10];
```

Why am I getting error saying "no matching constructor initialization of BuyOrder[10]"?

Below is the BuyOrder constructor. Do I have to make another default constructor?

```
BuyOrder::BuyOrder(double price, int quantity, Stock &s)
    :buyPrice{ price },
    buyQuantity{quantity},
    buyStock{ s } 
    {}
```

Comment: That is not a default constructor. The default constructor takes no arguments.

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: @MichaelAlbers So do you mean that I can only declare an array of object which the objects has default constructors ?

Comment: @JoviZhihaoZhou, no you can also perform aggregate initialization on it. But it's only feasible for very small arrays.

Comment: @StoryTeller In this case, if I do BuyOrder buy[10]; there shows no matching constructor initialization. May you suggest how to edit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in my comment, you [*can*](https://ideone.com/dic5J7) do aggregate initialization for small arrays.

```
#include <array>

struct example
{
    example(int, double) {}
    example(example const&) = delete;
};

int main() {

    example arr1[2] {
      {1, 3.4},
      {2, 5.6}
    };

    std::array<example, 2> arr2 {{
      {1, 3.4},
      {2, 5.6}
    }};

    return 0;
}
```